# Unordered Combo Selection To Enable Generate Button

Tags: java, button

http://s1194.photobucket.com/albums/aa371/RewindPlay/?action=view&current=downup.png

I have 3 sensors I am looking at. Sensors 1-3, all need to be !=0 until the generate button is enabled to throw the code (that was selected in the sensors by the user) into a hierarchy view.

I do have this working, but only when you select one after another top too bottom. 
(example: If you select the middle sensor (2), then the top (1), and then the bottom (3) - generate button stays greyed out and unable to generate.)

Is there a trick to make it so the user can select this in an unordered fashion?

I immediately thought of and/or operators, but Java does not have that.

Comment: *"I tried attaching an image but I am not yet allowed.."*  No problem, upload it to a free image site and provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

From the description of the requirement, it sounds as though 3 x [`JRadioButton`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRadioButton.html) in a [`ButtonGroup`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ButtonGroup.html) would do the trick.